# How do I setup Gmail for my VPS?

Tags: vps, email, gmail, mx-record

I'm using a Hostgator VPS running CentOS 5. I only have shell access (no control panel).

I'm supposed to change my MX records and add a CNAME record for verification. What should I do? I know it would have been really easy through some kind of a control panel but I really haven't been provided one. Thanks in advance.

Edit: first: http://www.howtoforge.com/bind-installation-on-centos
then, edit /var/named/yourdomain.com.zone to add the proper MX records. kthxbai

Answer (score 3):

Normally you talk with your DNS provider and insert those into their records. If you don't have one then you'd have to edit the files for your DNS daemon, but I strongly suspect that you're not running your own DNS server.

Comment: Yup, running my own DNS server. I got BIND installed and I've had to configure it to map my domain name to my IP following a tut that laid out the details. I was hoping there would be something similar for Google mail. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't anything special you need to do for Google Mail versus other services. Just add a MX record and a CNAME record and increment the serial.

Comment: Don't forget the little things, like SPF.

Comment: Have you read Google Apps help on the topic?  It is pretty straight-forward.  http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33352

Comment: Thanks, but how to do it through shell? Sorry if this is a noob question.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has nothing to do with your VPS. All you have to do is modify the DNS entries for your domain name.

You necessarily have a control panel to do such thing.

Comment: I really don't have a control panel, one that would let me graphically change the DNS settings. I need to do it through shell. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Go with Ignacio's advice and setup your MX records.

Comment: How do I do it in shell? Thanks.